# Rendering nested object properties from API call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-object, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to render text from an API call, text or numbers that are directly accesible from the axios.data object can render normally, nevertheless when inside the axios.data there is another object with its own properties I cannot render because an error shows, the error is 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'coin.description.en')', over there description is an object; my code is

```js
function SINGLE_COIN(props) {

    const { id } = useParams()
    console.log(id);
    

    const SINGLE_API = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}?tickers=true&market_data=true&community_data=true&developer_data=true&sparkline=true`

    const [coin, setCoin] = useState({})


     useEffect(() => {
        axios
    .get(SINGLE_API)
    .then(res => {
        setCoin(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    }, [])


    return (


        <div>
           <h2>{coin.name}</h2>
           <div>{coin.coingecko_score}</div>
           <div>{coin.liquidity_score}</div>
           <div>{coin.description.en}</div>


            <SINGLE_COIN_DATA coin={coin} />
        </div>

    )
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial render (data is not fetched yet), it will be empty. so nested  property would be undefined.

so note the changes:

##### Example 1:

`const [coin, setCoin] = useState(null);`

..

```
return (
    <div>
      {coin ? (
        <>
          <h2>{coin.name}</h2>
          <div>{coin.coingecko_score}</div>
          <div>{coin.liquidity_score}</div>
          <div>{coin.description.en}</div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
```

##### Example:2: Use the optional chaining while accessing nested property

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h2>{coin?.name}</h2>
      <div>{coin?.coingecko_score}</div>
      <div>{coin?.liquidity_score}</div>
      <div>{coin?.description?.en}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

And the complete code with : [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-axios-api-example-zg33e)

```js
export default function SINGLE_COIN() {
  const { id } = useParams()

  const SINGLE_API = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${id}?tickers=true&market_data=true&community_data=true&developer_data=true&sparkline=true`;

  const [coin, setCoin] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(SINGLE_API)
      .then((res) => {
        setCoin(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {coin ? (
        <>
          <h2>{coin.name}</h2>
          <div>{coin.coingecko_score}</div>
          <div>{coin.liquidity_score}</div>
          <div>{coin.description.en}</div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: in the working example the route params are commented and hardcoded value is passed to make the example simple.

Comment: Su useful buddy, tank you!